# Joining with wildcard not matching strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, wildcard

**BACKGROUND**

I have two tables:

`drugDistributionHistory` - details what/when drugs were distributed ti patients.

`drugPrices` - prices of drugs.

For this example, I am looking at drug called "FLUOXETINE", also known as "PROZAC".

If I query for this drug in the `drugPrices` table, I yield these results:

```
SELECT 
    drugName, 
    drugBrandName, 
    drugStrength, 
    drugDosage, 
    drugPrice 
FROM 
    drugPrices 
WHERE 
    drugName like '%fluoxetine%'
```

Results:

```
FLUOXETINE  PROZAC  10MG    CAP 0.02
FLUOXETINE  PROZAC  20MG    CAP 0.05
```

In my `drugDistributionHistory` table, I am looking for this same type of drug, however, the drug may be entered differently, for example:

```
select 
    drugName,
    strength,
    measurement 
from
    drugDistributionHistory ddh 
    INNER JOIN facilities f ON ddh.facilityId = f.facilityId
where
    f.facilityId = 40
    AND ddh.resultCode = 'Received'
    AND MONTH(dateGiven) = '01'
    AND YEAR(dateGiven) = '2014'
    and ddh.drugName like 'fluoxetine%'
```

order by 
    ddh.drugName

Results:

```
Fluoxetine / Prozac 60.00   mg
Fluoxetine / Prozac 20.00   mg
```

**QUESTION**

My query to try to match drugs with their prices looks like this. I am trying to match on either the `drugName` or the `drugBrandName` (ie: PROZAC is the brand name drug of FLUOXETINE):

```
select 
    drugName,
    strength,
    measurement 
from
    drugDistributionHistory ddh 
    INNER JOIN facilities f ON ddh.facilityId = f.facilityId
    INNER JOIN drugPrices dp ON
        ('%' + dp.drugName + '%' like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%' 
      OR '%' + dp.drugBrandName + '%' like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%')
where
    f.facilityId = 40
    AND ddh.resultCode = 'Received'
    AND MONTH(dateGiven) = '01'
    AND YEAR(dateGiven) = '2014' 
    and ddh.drugName like 'fluoxetine%'
order by 
    ddh.drugName
```

No results are found.

**Am I misinterpreting how to use wildcards when joining tables?**

Comment: I think the biggest misinterpretation is that you think it's a good idea.  Why would you not join on the drug id?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is coming from two completely different systems, and the only thing I can join on is the names of the drugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did put the percent signs on both sides of the `LIKE` operator, I suspect that you incorrectly believe that `LIKE` is symmetric; it is not. You do not get a match because neither `'%Fluoxetine%'` nor `'%Prozac%'` matches `'%Fluoxetine / Prozac%'` from the `drugDistributionHistory` table on the right side of the `LIKE` statement. However, you would get a match if your operands switch sides:

```
INNER JOIN drugPrices dp ON
    (ddh.drugName LIKE '%' + dp.drugName + '%'
  OR ddh.drugName LIKE '%' + dp.drugBrandName + '%')
```

The left-hand side of `LIKE` does not need `%` signs.

Comment: If you're not sure of the data quality, you should also do a trim : `ddh.drugName LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(dp.drugName)) + '%'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
INNER JOIN drugPrices dp ON
        ('%' + dp.drugName + '%' like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%' 
      OR '%' + dp.drugBrandName + '%' like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%')
```

Should be

```
INNER JOIN drugPrices dp ON
        (dp.drugName like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%' 
      OR dp.drugBrandName like '%' + ddh.drugName + '%')
```

Notice the removal of the % symbols on the source fields. You only use these on the right hand side of the LIKE operator.

Of course, this will only find results where the dp.drugName contains the ddh.drugName or the dp.drugBrandName contains the ddh.DrugName. Is this acceptable?

Comment: +1 "You only use % symbols on the right hand side of the LIKE operator."

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to table into account the delimiters around the drug name to avoid confusion (for instance, so "abc" won't match "abcd").  If so you can do this as:

```
from
    drugDistributionHistory ddh 
    INNER JOIN facilities f ON ddh.facilityId = f.facilityId
    INNER JOIN drugPrices dp ON
        (' ' + dp.drugName + ' ' like '% ' + ddh.drugName +  '%' 
      OR ' ' + dp.drugBrandName + ' ' like '% ' + ddh.drugName + ' %')
```